# Execute scheduled Apex class code on the Developer console

Tags: apex, query, scheduled-apex, developer-console

I have the following scheduled Apex code, I want to try it out on the developer console, as salesforce scheduler offers to the run the code, once an hour only.

```
global class examExpiryAlert implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        List<Exam__c> objects = [
            SELECT Name, Exam_state__c, Expiration_Date_WF__c, day7Alert__c 
            FROM Exam__c
            WHERE Exam_state__c = 'Active'];

        for(Exam__c e : objects){
            if(e.Expiration_Date_WF__c >= Date.today()-7){  
                e.day7Alert__c = True;
            } 
        }
        update objects;
    }
}
```

how can i run this code in the developer console to execute it right away, what parts do i have to remove or add?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
new examExpiryAlert().execute(null);
```

context doesn't matter.

Comment: this worked, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can create a cron expression to execute scheduleable class from Developer console.

```
String hour = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().hour());
String min = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().minute()); 
String ss = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().second());

//parse to cron expression
String nextFireTime = ss + ' ' + min + ' ' + hour + ' * * ?';

MyScheduledJob s = new MyScheduledJob(); 
System.schedule('Job Started At ' + String.valueOf(Datetime.now()), nextFireTime, s);
```

[Schedule Apex](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002809&type=1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute just a part of the class, you can extract the code and run that. However, Non atomic's way is best if you want all the functionality.

```
List<Exam__c> objects = [
SELECT Name, Exam_state__c, Expiration_Date_WF__c, day7Alert__c 
FROM Exam__c
WHERE Exam_state__c = 'Active'];

for(Exam__c e : objects){
    if(e.Expiration_Date_WF__c >= Date.today()-7){  
        e.day7Alert__c = True;
    } 
}
update objects;
```

Comment: this is also a good answer